# Why do devils curse by statistics?

Tags: a-tale-dark-and-grimm

In the Netflix series *A Tale Dark and Grimm*, the Devil and his grandmother frequently employ "statistics" as a curse word, presumably where a human would say "damn" or something along those lines.

The only connection that I can think of is a [famous quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies%2C_damned_lies%2C_and_statistics?wprov=sfla1) that positions statistics as worse than "damned lies," but that seems like a thin connection. Why do fiends curse by the discipline of statistics?

Comment: The origin of the quote is unclear, but it is very, *very* famous, thanks to it being repeated by Twain.  So that may be all there is to it.

Comment: You've nailed it.